# Tenant Id filter where Multi-tenancy in single database

Tags: spring

I'm using JDBCTemplate and not using Hibernate and running native SQL queries.

I need to attach/append tenant id to any query which is being executed.

For multiple database i come across this - https://github.com/openMF/mifosx-admin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mifosx/admin/domain/BaseDAO.java

Can someone help me with suggestion or comments how to attach the tenant id dynamically as jdbc interceptor or apply filter for queries?

Currently all queries goes like select * from...where tenant id = test

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the tenant id as soon as you can determine it's value, in a thread-local, perhaps facilitated by a servlet filter.

If all such entities implement an interface which exposes a 'tenantId' property,  Then update this property in your entity objects, from the above thread-local tenantId, in your BaseDAO class.

By way of example, you could create a singleton which keeps a threadlocal copy of your tenant id, assuming that it is an Integer. Here's one way to do this.

```
public enum ThreadState {
    INSTANCE
    ;
    private ThreadLocal<Integer> tenantId = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public void setTenantId(Integer tid) {
        tenantId.set(tid);
    }
    public Integer getTenantId() {
        return tenantId.get();
    }   
}
```

Then, in that place in your code where you determine what the tenant ID is for the given request, stash it into our new threadlocal as follows:

```
ThreadState.INSTANCE.setTenantId(tenantId);
```

And finally, in your DAO class where you are formulating a query and need to access the tenant ID write the following:

```
Integer tenantId = ThreadState.INSTANCE.getTenantId()
```

At this point you can use the tenantId when formulating your query, or update a new entity object prior to storing it.

Comment: Any BaseDAO example which has the tenantId property and resolution

Comment: Also needs an example for servlet filter to filter tenant id

Comment: It's impossible to provide much more detail. You havent described how your application determines what the tenant id is for any given request. Is it based off of a cookie, or other piece of data present in an an http request, or is it derived from something else, like the user who made the request?

If you create a service which stores a threadlocal tenantId. inject it into the code that figures out what the tenant id is and calls a method on this service to store it. Then inject it into your DAO classes or base DAO class to retrieve tenantId and update your entity or pass it into a query.

Comment: It is based on the user who has logged in. We will resolve the tenant id when the user has been validated and logged it. Tenant id will be resolved on successful login. Do you mean store the variable in thread local in controller layer and the same can be used in dao or service ? I can resolve the tenant id on user controller and put in http session. Need a proper way to propogate to dao or service whenever is required. passing as a parameter in controller may not be the right approach due to high maintenance

Comment: I've given you a strategy to solve your problem. You will find that examples of servlet filters, spring services, and thread-locals are plentiful, and are only a simple web-search away.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a servlet filter. If you already have code in your 'controller' that resolves the tenant id, and you don't want to directly pass this value to your persistence layer, then all you need to do is as I've described. You need a class (@Component, or singleton) to store the threadlocal and expose methods to set and get this property. Then call these methods at the pertinent place in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163607/discussion-between-kathir-and-tom-drake).